# How do I fix error 42000, Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. while implementing a stored procedure in visual studio for sql server?

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to implement a stored procedure which I have created in SQL Server, through Visual studio using a CSV file I have created using pandas. The stored procedure will simply enter the data from my CSV file into a target table called out in the stored procedure however I am encountering the error ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'." )any time I run the python code which I have detailed below.

I have tried various combinations of the code below and ensured my target table is structured as datetimes for all the date and time columns and varchar 50 as the description and area column.

```
CA=pd.read_csv('10514697.csv') #Name of my CSV

CA["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y') #Converting my date from object as in CSV to datetime as required
CA["TOC"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.TOC,format='%H:%M:%S')#Converting my TOC column from object to datetime and then converting it below to just time. I repeated this step for each time column in the CSV
CA["ORD"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.ORD,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA["MOB"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.MOB,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA["IA"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.IA,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA["LS"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.LS,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA["AH"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.AH,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA["MAV"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.MAV,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA["CD"]=pd.to_datetime(CA.CD,format='%H:%M:%S')
CA.Date=CA.Date.dt.date
CA["Station Area"] = CA["Station Area"].astype(str) # I convert the object to str, same done for description
CA["StationArea"]= CA["Station Area"] # I remove the space from the station area so it is a single word
CA.Description = CA.Description.astype(str)
CA.TOC = CA.TOC.dt.time
CA.ORD = CA.ORD.dt.time
CA.MOB = CA.MOB.dt.time
CA.IA = CA.IA.dt.time
CA.LS = CA.LS.dt.time
CA.AH = CA.AH.dt.time
CA.MAV = CA.MAV.dt.time
CA.CD = CA.CD.dt.time




import pypyodbc #establishing connection 
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL Server;Server=CPX-YKJPS50NNO9\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ABCRetail')
try:
    sqlCommand = "EXEC uspCSVInserts (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" #calling the required USP with the required amount of parameters
    values = CA[['Date','StationArea', 'Description', 'TOC', 'ORD', 'MOB', 'IA', 'LS', 'AH', 'MAV', 'CD']].values.tolist() #converting all of the values in the CSV into a list for entry into the target table
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sqlCommand, values) #The code fails at this point and does not progress to the commit stage
    cursor.commit()
except Exception as ex:
    print("Failed to execute stored procedure due to :", ex)

finally: 
    if (connection.connected):
        connection.close()


Stored procedure code in SQL server is as follows:
@Date datetime,
@StationArea varchar(50),
@Description varchar(50),
@TOC datetime,
@ORD datetime,
@MOB datetime,
@IA datetime,
@LS datetime,
@AH datetime,
@MAV datetime, 
@CD datetime

AS 
INSERT into BigData
([Date], StationArea, [Description], TOC, ORD, MOB, IA, LS, AH, CD)
Values
(@Date, @StationArea, @Description, @TOC,@ORD, @MOB, @IA, @LS, @AH, @CD)
```

I was expecting the code to run through and input the data in my CSV into the table in my sql server database but it constantly fails at the point detailed.

Comment: Since this code does not appear to have any references to a variable `@P1`, this is most likely an error in a trigger against the target table. Alternate explanations include the possibility that it is pointing to a different database than you expect, or a different server, which has a different version of the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi Vergil, I've had a look into it and still can't figure it out. I assumed the P1 just referred to the first parameter and was the arbitary name given to the first parameter. Having set up the table, database and server I can be sure that they're pointing at the right place.

Comment: Well, the next thing I would try is removing the parentheses around the parameters. Calling an SQL Server stored procedure does not require the parameters to be within parentheses.

Comment: Thanks Vergil, I have updated the code to using a call rather than an exec statement and the error has now changed from @P1 to
NaTType does not support strftime.
Any suggestions to how I can fix this would be hugely appreciated.
From what I can gather online, NaTType seems to be for null or empty values in a given dataset? So my interpretation of the error is that it is something to do with null values in my time columns or does this sound incorrect? I can't drop the rows with blanks/nulls in them though as this would mean we are losing data records for a single blank cell